# How to extend a packaged enum

Tags: objective-c

If I have a packaged enum like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Type) {
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC
};
```

How can I extend it to include a `TypeD`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The capability to do so would violate the assumptions under which existing code works.